# Why does setting `overflow-x: hidden` on `html` cause a child's `position: sticky` element to behave differently?

Tags: html, css, sticky

The following two example are identical except the first example applies `overflow-x: hidden` to only the `body`, while the second example applies it to both `html, body`.

Why does the first example works as expected while the second one does not?

### This works as expected:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

p.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p class="sticky">foo</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
```

### But, this doesn't:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

p.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p class="sticky">foo</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius magnam odio quidem nisi? Dolorum voluptatibus voluptas dignissimos cupiditate vel voluptates ducimus ullam, cumque vitae. Doloribus quasi eaque consequuntur voluptatibus sunt!</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what the CSS positioning spec has to say about [`position:sticky`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#sticky-pos)

> **6.2. Sticky positioning**
>
> A stickily positioned box is positioned similarly to a relatively positioned box, but the offset is computed with reference to the nearest ancestor with a scrolling box, or the viewport if no ancestor has a scrolling box.

So the matter here is: what is the nearest ancestor with a scrolling box, as opposed what box is scrolled by the vertical scroll bar?

To understand that, we need to take into account overflow propagation. The [CSS overflow spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-propagation) says:

> **3.4. Overflow Viewport Propagation**
>
> UAs must apply the overflow-* values set on the root element to the viewport. However, when the root element is an [HTML] html element (including XML syntax for HTML) whose overflow value is visible (in both axes), and that element has a body element as a child, user agents must instead apply the overflow-* values of the first such child element to the viewport. The element from which the value is propagated must then have a used overflow value of visible.

So, in the first case

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

the overflow properties of the body element are propagated to the viewport. Because of that propagation, there's no ancestor element of `p.sticky` that has a scrolling box, so the sticky offset gets computed relative to the viewport. The viewport is also the box that gets scrolled by the vertical scrollbar.

In the second case,

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

it's the overflow properties of the html element that get propagated to the viewport, and the body element retains its specified overflow properties, establishing a scrolling box that's the ancestor of `p.sticky`. The offset is then computed relative to the body element. But it's not the body element that the vertical scrollbar works on, it's still the viewport.

So `p.sticky` doesn't move relative to the body element, and as the whole thing moves there's nothing for `p.sticky` to get stuck against.

Comment: some insight here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642611/prevent-white-space-between-selected-text-lines ?