# Prevent white space between selected text lines

Tags: html, css

How come when a user selects multiple lines of text inside a single element, the selection background has no gaps in it, but if I put each line in a separate element, white lines appear?

Consider this snippet:

```css
.line {
  font-family: 'Courier';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">Text 1
Text 2</div>
<div class="line">Text 3</div>
<div class="line">Text 4</div>
```

If all the text is selected, first two lines are "merged" together, but white lines appear before third and fourth lines, even though the distance between actual text in all four lines is identical?

[image]

How do I get rid of them without changing font or spacing?

Comment: why is this a problem.

Comment: Because it looks ugly when you select a large block of text.

Comment: change your line-height to 16px; That's the only way. Or change your padding.

Comment: It actually depends on the browser, on Firefox you'll se the white gap even between Text 1 and Text 2.

Comment: if you want more *strange* behavior use a big value of line-height ... and also try a big value of line + inline-block on your elements

Comment: Oh ok I guess I have to set line height to some magic value that depends on font size.How do I compute it though, other than trying every value and seeing if it works? I need it to look like a text editor, and they never have gaps in selected text.

Comment: don't set any line-height and it will be fine

Comment: I need to know the exact height line for virtual scrolling. Measuring an invisible element beforehand could work, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a `line-height: 1;` or `line-height: 1.1;` but your text loses in readibility.
I usually set a `line-height: 1.6;` for font sizes around 14px.

```css
.line {
  font-family: 'Courier';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">Text 1
Text 2</div>
<div class="line">Text 3</div>
<div class="line">Text 4</div>
```

Comment: In Chrome there's a noticeable overlap between selection boxes that is darker than the rest of the selection.